# How to match sequence group?

Tags: regex

say, the given string is `abcwhateverdefwhatever34567whatever012` How to match those group which are in sequence like match `abc, def, 34567,012`?

the regex i have now is `(.)\1{2,}` but it matches the same characters but not in sequence

Comment: You can't do this with regex. Depending on the language you are using you could perhaps do this by looking at the numeric representation of the individual `char`s.

Comment: Regular expression is not meant for this task.

Comment: @NokImchen: use `ord` and iterate along the string, comparing each `ord` with the previous character's `ord`.

Comment: @nneonneo the string is huge like 10MB, so i wanted to use regex for simplicity. Anyways, thanks :)

Comment: @NokImchen if you have a `10MB` string I really wouldn't recommend regex unless you **really** know what you are doing... Walking along the string and using `ord` as suggested is an `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: The better question is why you have to do this with a 10MB string...in PHP...

Comment: @nneonneo yup, right! my bad, anyways, now i'm coding using your ord method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still looking for PHP code.

```
function getSequence($str) {
    $prev = 0; $next = 0; $length = strlen($str);

    $temp = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $next = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($next == $prev + 1) {
            $temp .= $str[$i];
        } else {
            if (strlen($temp) > 1) $result[] = $temp;
            $temp = $str[$i];
        }
        $prev = $next;
    }

    if (strlen($temp) > 1) $result[] = $temp;

    return $result;
}

$str = "abcwhateverdefwhatever34567whatever012";
print_r(getSequence($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that solves the problem with regex. It's not very efficient though and I wouldn't recommend it.

```
from re import findall, X

text = "abcwhateverdefwhatever34567whatever012"

reg = r"""
(?:
(?:0(?=1))|
(?:(?<=0)1)|(?:1(?=2))|
(?:(?<=1)2)|(?:2(?=3))|
(?:(?<=2)3)|(?:3(?=4))|
(?:(?<=3)4)|(?:4(?=5))|
(?:(?<=4)5)|(?:5(?=6))|
(?:(?<=5)6)|(?:6(?=7))|
(?:(?<=6)7)|(?:7(?=8))|
(?:(?<=7)8)|(?:8(?=9))|
(?:(?<=8)9)|

(?:a(?=b))|
(?:(?<=a)b)|(?:b(?=c))|
(?:(?<=b)c)|(?:c(?=d))|
(?:(?<=c)d)|(?:d(?=e))|
(?:(?<=d)e)|(?:e(?=f))|
(?:(?<=e)f)
){1,}
"""

print findall(reg, text, X)
```

The result is:

```
['abc', 'def', '34567', '012']
```

As you can see I only added the numbers and the first 6 letters in the alphabet. It's should be fairly obvious how to continue.